# Japanese Old kanji form

Tags: kanji, reading-comprehension

[image]

Hi,
 I am looking for the middle kanji in Kutani Wata xx sei. I guess it is ''no'' but this particular form of the character does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It is 「{の}」, which is a variant of 「野{の}」.

Thus, 「綿」 is indeed read 「わたの」.

https://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%F0%A1%8C%9B/page.html

「綿野/綿」 was the name of a major porcelain dealer that exported the famous [九谷焼{くたにやき} (Kutani ware)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutani_ware) to other countries

For the advanced learners, another variant of 「野」, which you will encounter far more often than you will 「」 would be 「埜」.

Comment: @ l'électeur Can I ask how you searched for the character on the moji.tekkai site? Stroke numbers? Reading?

Comment: Thanks for the info. However the coding is strange  I need UTF 8 based on 3 bits